# word breaking in html emails on yahoo (firefox mobile browser)

Tags: html, email, firefox, yahoo, mobile-browser

As you can see in the pic, the words are breaking in the same `<div>` which shouldn't happen. I checked to see if a word-wrap property was being applied to it and it was. So I tried overriding that property my own inline style and `!important`. Still didn't work. Interestingly, the same mail opens fine in Gmail on Firefox browser, and in the Chrome browser it opens fine on Yahoo and Gmail. Please suggest what I can do to rectify this html mail.

[image: example]

Comment: Please give image as image, not url. That would be more helpful for all users. No need to give whole text as a link.